# Rule for questions like "Or is it?"

Tags: grammar

I just saw two sentences like

> Doing this is right. Or is it?

To me it looks like the first sentence rephrases a common belief while the second announces the belief to be proved wrong later. Am I right?

The strange thing about this construction is that both sentences are positive. Logically I'd expect the question to be something like "Or maybe is it wrong at the end?" - this way it could be expressed e.g. in German. Is there an explanations while the English construction goes "the other way round"?

---

OK, it's metanoia, but I'm still stuck with the exact phrasing. Nowhere I've seen this form. Would a phrase like

> Doing this is right. Or isn't it?

be correct as well and mean the same?

Comment: Um, the second statement is not "positive". It is a *question*. "It is" and "Is it?" are not the same type of statement. (And if that weren't enough already, they even threw in an *or* for good measure.) Exactly the same as in German, BTW. "Das ist richtig. Ist es das?" Also, note how you yourself just asked "Am I right?" You didn't ask, "Or maybe am I [sic] wrong at the end?" In short, I'm afraid I don't quite understand what is causing the confusion for you. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Unlike "isn't it?", the second statement is a question using no negation - that's what I meant by "positive". As I wrote "Am I right?" I was really asking if I am right; it was no rhetorical figure introducing a discussion about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We, like children, often assert things as positive when in actual fact they are a little less than absolute truth, or even false.  Posing a question after an assertion this way is a very strong way to indicate a truth value somewhere close to the middle, a truth of which there is considerable doubt [nowhere near absolute].  It introduces a certain state of mind in the reader.

In that sense, you are right.  The initial belief is proved wrong later.

A positive statement is stronger than a negative one.  So "Or is it?" introduces more doubt than "Or isn't it?" although both do mean the same.

Answer (score 6):

Your example is an instance of the rhetorical figure called **metanoia**: Making a statement and then correcting or questioning it so as to possibly refute it.

Examples:

> If she come in, she'll surely speak to my wife / My wife, my wife! What wife? — Shakespeare, *Othello*, Act 5, Scene 2
>
> No other should taste the happiness I scorn. Why do I say happiness? — Fielding, *Joseph Andrews*